# I have bug in my query, have no idea what happen. When I run below code it produce 20 rows 16 are duplicate rows but I remove field c.qty then Ok

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    A.PACKINGSLIPID, A.ITEMID, A.QTY, 
    D.INVENTBATCHID, C.ORIGPURCHID, c.QTY, C.PURCHUNIT 
FROM
    INVENTTRANS A 
LEFT JOIN 
    VENDPACKINGSLIPTRANS C ON A.PACKINGSLIPID = C.PACKINGSLIPID 
INNER JOIN 
    INVENTDIM D ON A.INVENTDIMID = D.INVENTDIMID 
WHERE 
    C.ORIGPURCHID = 'PO-SIZA-000003809'
    AND A.DATAAREAID = C.DATAAREAID 
GROUP BY 
    A.PACKINGSLIPID, A.ITEMID, A.QTY, D.INVENTBATCHID, 
    C.ORIGPURCHID, c.qty, C.PURCHUNIT
```

Comment: By having this `A.DATAAREAID=C.DATAAREAID` in your where clause, you are making that C table an inner join. Perhaps move that to your left join. Sample data and desired output may be helpful.

Comment: Y1234567 RIN-000104 100 CCB-18UC-110222 PO-SIZA-000003809 5 cs
Y1234567 RIN-000104 100 CCB-18UC-110222 PO-SIZA-000003809 20 cs
Y1234567 RIN-000104 100 CCB-18UC-110222 PO-SIZA-000003809 80 cs
Y1234567 RIN-000104 100 CCB-18UC-110222 PO-SIZA-000003809 100 cs Actually it should be in one line but system duplicating it.

Comment: This is correct query SELECT A.PACKINGSLIPID, A.ITEMID, A.QTY, D.INVENTBATCHID, C.ORIGPURCHID,  C.PURCHUNIT FROM INVENTTRANS A --WHERE PACKINGSLIPID ='INV#492903'
 left JOIN VENDPACKINGSLIPTRANS C
ON A.PACKINGSLIPID = C.PACKINGSLIPID
iNNER JOIN INVENTDIM D
ON A.INVENTDIMID = D.INVENTDIMID 
WHERE 
C.ORIGPURCHID = 'PO-SIZA-000003809'
and A.DATAAREAID = C.DATAAREAID
AND A.PACKINGSLIPID IS NOT NULL
AND C.PURCHUNIT IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY A.PACKINGSLIPID, A.ITEMID, A.QTY, D.INVENTBATCHID, C.ORIGPURCHID,  C.PURCHUNIT

Comment: Y1234567 RIN-000104 100.000000 CCB-18UC-110222 PO-SIZA-000003809 cs
Y1234567 RIN-000148 480.000000 CCB-18UC-110122 PO-SIZA-000003809 cs
Y1234567 RIN-000149 60.000000 CCB-18UC-110222 PO-SIZA-000003809 cs
Y1234567 RIN-000150 60.000000 CCB-18UC-110222 PO-SIZA-000003809 cs
Y1234567 RIN-000151 30.000000 CCB-18UC-110222 PO-SIZA-000003809 cs
 Out put of correct query

Comment: Please edit your question rather than adding those bits of info to the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Dynamics AX.  Your duplicates are coming from the fact that VendPackingSlipTrans and InventTrans is a many to many relationship.

As commenters have pointed out, specifying in the where clause that the left joined table contain a value is the same as making it an inner join.  My guess is that they thing you're really trying to do is this:

```
SELECT 
    VENDPACKINGSLIPTRANS.PACKINGSLIPID, 
    VENDPACKINGSLIPTRANS.ITEMID, 
    VENDPACKINGSLIPTRANS.QTY, 
    INVENTDIM.INVENTBATCHID, 
    VENDPACKINGSLIPTRANS.ORIGPURCHID, 
    VENDPACKINGSLIPTRANS.PURCHUNIT 
FROM        VENDPACKINGSLIPTRANS
INNER JOIN  INVENTDIM
ON          INVENTDIM.[PARTITION] = VENDPACKINGSLIPTRANS.[PARTITION] 
AND         INVENTDIM.DATAAREAID = VENDPACKINGSLIPTRANS.DATAAREAID 
AND         INVENTDIM.INVENTDIMID = VENDPACKINGSLIPTRANS.INVENTDIMID 
WHERE       VENDPACKINGSLIPTRANS.ORIGPURCHID = 'PO-SIZA-000003809'
```

Notice I'm joining on Partition, DataAreaId, and InventDimId.  That's because all the AX indices except the RECID index have partition at the beginning.  Since InventDim has a unique index on Partition/DataAreaId/InventDimId, I know I'm not going to get any duplicates, every line is vendor packing slip line.

If you neeeeed the InventTrans, the VendPackingSlipTrans does have an InventTransId field, but remember there is not necessarily one InventTrans record per InventTransId.  You can't obviate the need to understand the data model by chucking a bunch of group bys at the problem.